# Is it possible to network a computer without a NIC by dialing into a computer that has one?

Tags: networking, dial-up

We have a Windows 98 desktop with a bunch of files on it. The computer is in perfect working order, except for the fact that the left-click on the mouse is broken (which kind of sucks). We don't have any other PS/2 mice. Nothing against the computer, but there are files on there we'd like on other computers now and not that one. I can't plug in a USB flash drive because a) it doesn't have the drivers and b) It only does USB 1, not USB 2/3. I couldn't get any newer flash drives or USB mice to work on the system.

I'm working on a fun small side-project right now with the Raspberry Pi. I'm looking to connect a serial port to the Pi and connect maybe a 56k modem to that. I would connect the modem to my PBX.

I also use a more modern computer running Windows 10. Using a serial connection, I plan to connect an acoustic coupler to it so I can use another telephone on the PBX to "dial in" to the Raspberry Pi.

Basically, just like the BBS days. The Raspberry Pi will function as the 'server' and the Windows 10 machine would function as the 'client'.

I'd also have an Ethernet cable plugged in on the Pi, so by dialing in I would theoretically have network and Internet access from the Windows 10 machine (even if I unplugged its Ethernet cable).

This got me thinking. Our WIN98 PC doesn't have a NIC. It does have a phone jack in it. If I used a direct modem connection or a serial acoustic modem connection to "dial in" to the Pi from the Windows 98 PC (the Windows 98 PC would then be the 'client'), would I be able to get network access? Would that machine be "on the network" from other computers? Furthermore, would it be able to access the Internet?

(Basically, will the Windows 98 PC be able to network just by dialing into a computer that *is* networked?)

Or would I have to actually configure the Raspberry Pi as an official "dial-up server" in order to do that?

In the late mainstream BBS days, maybe around '95, BBSs started offering Internet access transparent to their users. They were still BBSs, not dial up servers, but they had Internet connectivity so people who dialed into the BBS got Internet connectivity as well. Basically, would that model work here?

Not sure if this setup would call for the computer dialed in to be an actual part of the network. As far as I know, the BBS was connected to the Internet and functioned as the middle man, doing the job of actually sending and receiving packets, printing out any results to the screen, and serially sending them to the client...

Comment: does it have PCI? You could throw in a PCI NIC into it...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not entirely sure, but I'm not going to open it up or anything.

Comment: USB is backwards compatible.  This means USB 3 devices can be plugged into a host that only understands USB 1 the only question is file system compatibility.  With Windows 98 that's limited to FAT32

Comment: @InterLinked You can ask all you want about that, doesn't mean it can be done, was trying to present an actual solution that would work.  I am more then willing to take my ball and go home if your going to dismiss actual actionable solutions the way you have.

Comment: win98 would often lack drivers. While there's means to get USB keys working on that os, that *is* outside the scope of what he wants

Comment: ... I wonder if a plain null modem style serial connection would work instead.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I was considering that, but it seems more fun to have it go through my PBX, just like the good old days. Also, I can use straight through cables instead of a null modem cable.

Comment: FYI:  I remember the dial up days, the max I could get is 25mb/hour hope you don't have to transfer too much as it could take ages.

Comment: @cybernard Not worried about speed at all. 300bps is slow anyhow. I just want to know if this is technically feasible. Even if I do the file transfer another way.

Comment: You could just get a USB modem plug it into the raspberry pi in one step.  As long as you have a modem at each end you should be able to connect.  You would have to setup a dial in server on the pi.  It might take a bunch of work, but you should be able to connect it to your network.  Straight serial to serial using the x or zmodem protocol has less setup work, but will transfer files.  You will need software clients on each end which support the same protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

I'm sorry that this answer seems so flimsy, but the technically correct answer is that there isn't just one definite yes-or-no answer that is universally true in all circumstances.  The specific, technically-correct answer seems to be hardware-dependent.  (In other words, it depends on what hardware you're using.)

To keep things simple, I'm going to just ignore the complexity of adding a PBX configuration into the mix.  I'm simply going to answer:

- If there are two computing devices with modems, can they connect directly to each other?
- Once connected, can I then have one share Internet access with another?

I believe the answer to those questions will provide you with the information you need, and then you can adjust things (like placing a PBX system in the middle), and if something doesn't work then you can get an idea of what adjustments may be sensible to try next.

So, on with the first question:

> If there are two computing devices with modems, can they connect directly to each other?

Sometimes.

I have had that work (by having one computer use ATX3D to blind dial, and the other computer use ATA).  I've also had it not work.  There is some suspicion that this may be related to the phone cord used, but from what I remember from experiences and reading, this can just be due to incompatibilities by one or both of the modems.  You can try.  If it doesn't work, you could try replacing one (or both) of the modems.  (Or the phone cord.)  It can work, but apparently not with all equipment.  This is such a rarely-attempted feat that manufacturers don't list this as a major feature, so the easiest way to know is to give it a try.

> Or would I have to actually configure the Raspberry Pi as an official "dial-up server" in order to do that?

Typically when there is a connection, the result is a "dumb terminal" connection.

Once you have a "dumb terminal" connection (where you can type messages back and forth), from that point, if you want to just transfer files, the traditional BBS-like method was using a dedicated protocol like Z-Modem.

However, you could get IP to work.  This will require some sort of software to pull off, and may take a bit of effort to configure.  I don't suggest even starting to try to configure that until you've confirmed that the hardware connects well enough to make a "dumb terminal"-style connection.  When you do get to that point, then you may benefit by providing IP capability.

The way I've seen that done (back in the days when dial-up access was more common in America) was using protocols such as PPP or C[SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol), or using a shell account and running programs (possibly including [SLiRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slirp)).  Running such programs worked better when using a shell account by using rlogin, rather than using a shell account by using with telnet.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the hard drive out, and get a USB enclosure.  Then put the hard drive in the USB enclosure and connect it to your regular PC.  This is probably the fastest option.

The company LapLink used to have a version of there product that supported serial to serial connection.  Maybe you could find a used one on ebay or etc.

Comment: I support the USB enclosure solution. The disk is probably PATA so OP should choose a right enclosure. SATA-only enclosure won't help.

Answer (score -2):

-Windows- -No USB- -No NIC-

Oh well...

-Raspberry- -Audio-

Stop hurting yourself. Do you have an internet connection?

If so try TeamViewer:
https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Comment: Enlighten me... how to connect to the INTERNET without a NETWORK INTERFACE CARD???